# How can I use laravel Auditor in controller

Tags: php, laravel

I used laravel Auditor in a model and it works very well as following:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;

class Contracts extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;

     protected $fillable=['condatereceived'];

    public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        } 
}
```

But I want to used it in the controller as :

```
public function updatecomplated(Request $request, $id,Contracts $contract ,Auditor $auditor)
{
     Contracts::where('id', $id)
     ->update(['complated' => 50, 'conuploadby' => Auth::id(),'constatus' =>'Need To Active' ]);

     if ($audit = $auditor->execute($contract)) {
        $auditor->prune($contract);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

The code in controller give me error:

> Call to undefined method OwenIt\Auditing\Facades\Auditor::execute()

any ideas to use auditor in the controller, please.

Answer (score 1):

try this [package](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-auditable) its easy with good documentation

simply add this to your table

```
$table->auditable();
```

and this to your model

```
namespace App;

use Yajra\Auditable\AuditableTrait;

class User extends Model
{
    use AuditableTrait;
}
```

thats it now simply get your auditor by calling

```
$user->creator // for who create
```

and

```
$user->updater //for who update data
```

for more information [click here](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-auditable/blob/master/src/AuditableTrait.php) for check trait
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it